# Choose the SDK version (e.g. preview3 vs preview2) that the dotnet CLI uses

Tags: dotnet-cli, .net-core

We have three versions of the `dotnet` command line interface installed:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk> dir -name
1.0.0-preview2-003133          
1.0.0-preview2-1-003177        
1.0.0-preview3-004056
```

How can we choose which version to use when running for instance `dotnet restore`? Right now the version is always the `preview3` build.

Our PATH contains `C:\Program Files\dotnet\` which contains:

```
host                           
sdk                            
shared                         
swidtag                        
dotnet.exe                     
LICENSE.txt                    
ThirdPartyNotices.txt
```

How do we choose which SDK the `dotnet.exe` uses?

Comment: I think I am in the same situation as yours. I want the dotnet CLI to use a specific version of the SDK. Did you manage to get it working that way?

Comment: Yes. The accepted answer worked for me @VivekRagunathan

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You choose which CLI you use by placing a [global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/global-json) file into the current directory or a directory above it.

For example, to select `1.0.0-preview2-003133`, the file would look like this:

```json
{
  "sdk": { "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003133" }
}
```

Comment: Hint about "current directory" was a life savior for me since I am using out of the source tree building. Where did you find this information?

Comment: @jariq [You should be able to find it in the official documentation about global.json soon.](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/pull/1839)